# What is "linear.predictors" as extractable from stan_glm() object in "rstanarm" package?

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan, hierarchical-bayesian, rstanarm

I'm writing to find out what is `"linear.predictors"` as returned by 
`stan_glm()` object.

Apparently, `"linear.predictors"` is not the same as the predictor(s) provided by the user (*documentation didn't help*).

In any case, is there a way to obtain predictor values from a `stan_glm()` object?

**Here is a single predictor (i.e., mom_iq) example:**

```
library(rstanarm) 
data(kidiq)
d <- kidiq  

fit <-stan_glm(kid_score ~ mom_iq,
           data = d,   
           prior = normal(0, 2.5),  
           prior_intercept = normal(0, 10),  
           prior_aux = cauchy(0, 100)) 


 max(fit$linear.predictors) # 110.5605   # As can be seen, these are not the same

 max(d$mom_iq)              # 138.8931
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is unclear from the documentation to [`stanreg-objects`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rstanarm/versions/2.17.2/topics/stanreg-objects)?

> ...
>   `fitted.values` Fitted mean values. For GLMs the linear predictors are transformed by the inverse link function.
>   `linear.predictors` Linear fit on the link scale. For linear models this is the same as fitted.values.
>   ...

Comment: @morouzian Your data is stored in `fit$data` and the terms are listed in `fit$terms`; but why can't you get the data directly from `d`?

Comment: @rnorouzian Your comment (which you unfortunately deleted) asked how to *"obtain the user's predictor values from a `stanreg-objects` object"*. Obviously this implies your data, doesn't it? What exactly is it that you are after?